# “twice the height of” is it a noun or an adjective?

Tags: comparative, auxiliary-verbs

[A] Which is correct?

> 1. Tower A **is** twice the height of tower B.
> 2. Tower A **has** twice the height of tower B.

Is the phrase "the height of" used as a noun (height) or as an adjective (high)?

[B] Which is correct?

> 1. Russia **is** twice the amount of military personnel of Ukraine.
> 2. Russia **has** twice the amount of military personnel of Ukraine.

Answer (score 1):

It's used as an adjective, so A is 1 . Twice the height is a measurement of an intrinsic property of the tower. In your second example, however, we use 'has' because troops are possessed by Russia, not an intrinsic quality of it. So B is 2. Here's an example to better detail the difference:

A. My height is equal to two yardsticks.

B. I have two yardsticks.